# Understanding pip install logs

Tags: python, pip

I'm trying to install "uds-client" package with "lwes" as transitive dependency. Both packages are present in our local Artifactory, but only first gets downloaded:

```
Collecting lwes==0.1.0 (from uds-client->-r requirements.txt (line 1))
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement lwes==0.1.0 (from uds-client->-r requirements.txt (line 1)) (from versions: 0.0.0)
```

In our Artifactory we have lwes in two versions 0.0.0 and 0.1.0.

1. Why it could not find a matching version of the package?
2. What does it mean "from versions: 0.0.0?

Comment: `from versions: 0.0.0` give a list of available versions and means that version `0.0.0` the available in the repository, `0.1.0` is not.

Comment: I found an answer: there was version 0.1.0 in the repo but for Python 3.5, while I need one for Python 2.7 :-)